# Can you use arcpy.Copy_management() with in_memory tables?

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a table in an ArcSDE GDB I'd like to step through using Python. For performance reasons I wanted to load it into memory like so:

`arcpy.Copy_management('C:/GDB.sde/MyTable', 'in_memory\\MyNewTable')`

When I tried this in IDLE I got:

`===================  RESTART ===================`

Running it in the Python window in ArcMap brought the whole program down. So my question is, can `Copy_management` actually be used to copy a table into memory? The [Esri documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000051000000) is pretty vague on what kinds of data you can pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though the "Copy" command is really used to copy/paste data between identical structures.

> Copies input data and pastes the output to the same or another location regardless of size. **The data type of the input and output data element is identical.**

You're probably better off simply going with the [CopyRows](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n4000000) command, which should allow you to copy the table into memory.

> The output table can be saved in a dBASE, ArcSDE geodatabase, file
>   geodatabase, or personal geodatabase, or as an INFO table.

From experience, though, you can also save to the in_memory workspace.

Answer (score 5):

From [this](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp00000003000260.htm) document:

> The "in_memory" workspace is not supported as the output location.

Comment: Wow, the error code and everything.  Nice find!