# Copying features from 'in_memory' to 'in_memory' using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, copy, in-memory

I came across [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50823/can-you-use-arcpy-copy-management-with-in-memory-tables) post and found out about [Copy_management()](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001700000051000000).

Is it possible to copy an *in_memory* feature to another *in_memory* feature?

I tried to test it using the following code, which fails:

```
shp = r"D:\test\somefile.shp"

bufferOne = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(shp,r"in_memory\bufferOne",'1 meters')

copyOfFirst = arcpy.Copy_management(bufferOne,r'in_memory\BufferOneCopy')
```

Trying the exact same thing with absolute paths, instead of *in_memory* works fine. Therefore I assume you cannot copy from *in_memory* to *in_memory*, or am I missing something? Would there be a way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Did you get an [ERROR 000260](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp00000003000260.htm) or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Use the Copy_Features GP tool for that.

```
pnt_fc = r"C:\Users\us\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\_PointDistanceFc"

mem1 = r"in_memory\bufferOne"
mem2 = r"in_memory\bufferTwo"

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features=pnt_fc,
                      out_feature_class=mem1,
                      buffer_distance_or_field='10 Meters')

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(mem1,mem2)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(mem2,r"C:\Users\us\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\out123")
```

When you use the following approach:

```
mem1 = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features=pnt_fc,
                      out_feature_class=r"in_memory\bufferOne",
                      buffer_distance_or_field='10 Meters')

mem2 = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(mem1,r"in_memory\bufferTwo")

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(mem2,r"C:\Users\us\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\out123")
```

You are getting mem1 and mem2 of type `<class 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjects.Result'>`, you should be aware of this if you are planning to interact with those objects.

Comment: It's Copy_management not CopyFeatures_management being used.

Comment: True, but the question was "My question is if it is possible to copy an in_memory feature to another in_memory feature."

Comment: You're right - I was distracted by the title which did not fully summarize the content.

Comment: The reason I ended up working with Copy_management is because CopyFeatures_management always spits out an error message for me when trying to save into memory, so I assumed it cannot be used to save into memory. I will have to try your code snippet later, and I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to save the output of the Copy tool to `in_memory`, whatever the input's workspace. It is explained in the last answer of the post you mentioned, I add [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00251-00275-000260.htm) an updated reference.

FYI, there are some other tools that don't accept `in_memory` as output workspace, e.g. [Project](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00926-00950-000944.htm).

Comment: I agree - Copy_management can only be used between workspaces of the same type.  Otherwise an [ERROR 000260](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp00000003000260.htm) will result.